# Cookie Management

Tags: magento2, session, cookie

Looking at adding functionality to the Cookie consent, instead of just accepting them I would like to add a new button which takes you to the a new page where you can select which cookies you would want on the page.

Not sure the best way to implement, I have figured out how to set/delete cookies but when it comes to third party ones they just re-appear.

I have seen the Amasty extension
https://amasty.com/cookie-consent-for-magento-2.html

Comment: I am also looking for that, any response ?